# PostgreSQL: Invalid token in query for json array containing column value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm working on writing a function for a Postgres 15 database that will (among other things) take query params and select matching items from a table, `features`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_ids(query_params json)
RETURNS TABLE(id bigint) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT id
    FROM features
    WHERE
      (CASE WHEN query_params->'id' IS NOT NULL THEN (query_params->'id')::jsonb @> features.id::text::jsonb ELSE true END) AND
      (CASE WHEN query_params->'category' IS NOT NULL THEN (query_params->'category')::jsonb @> features.category::text::jsonb ELSE true END);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT PARALLEL SAFE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

So far, this function works just fine for integers:

```sql
-- typecasting the input here, since I'm doing a manual test
SELECT select_ids('{"id": [123,543]}'::json);
-- returns
--    id
-- ---------
--    123
--    543
```

However, for an array of text values, it breaks down:

```sql
-- typecasting the input here, since I'm doing a manual test
SELECT select_ids('{"category": ["type1","type2"]}'::json);
-- ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
-- DETAIL:  Token "type5" is invalid.
```

`Token "type5" is invalid` is in fact the real error. That value is present in the table, though I'm not querying for it. It seems that the `category` field of the table isn't being converted to json properly before the comparison, but I don't know what to do about it.

**UPDATE**

Also supporting the hypothesis that I'm not handling `category` - a custom enum type - correctly in some way:

```sql
SELECT category::text::jsonb FROM features LIMIT 10;
-- ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
-- DETAIL: Token "type5" is invalid
```

The `category` field's type is `my_category`:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_category AS enum (
 'type1', 'type2', 'type3'
);
```

The query `SELECT 'type5'::jsonb` throws the same error as above. It seems to be true that plain text - just a string without object or array brackets - cannot be converted to json or jsonb in postgres. This does work with numbers, however: `SELECT 4.3::jsonb;`, for example.

Comment: The error `DETAIL:  Token "type5" is invalid.` does not match the input `'{"category": ["type1","type2"]}'::json`

Comment: I know it - it's a value that is present in the table I'm querying though. That's what makes me think something is going wrong with converting the `category` column to json, rather that something wrong with the way I'm formatting the function call. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: What does `select category::text::jsonb from features` return for some sample of the data?

Comment: 1) On further reflection the error says `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json` and the only place in the function I see a `json` type is the argument `query_params json`.  Is there maybe another function named `select_ids`?  In `psql` doing `\df *.select_ids` would show if there is more then one. 2) What is the table data type for `features.category`? **Add answers as text update to question text**.

Comment: This `SELECT '"type5"'::jsonb; "type5"` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token `type5` is an invalid JSON token indeed.

Valid JSON tokens are the literals `null`, `true`, `false`; numbers, strings in double quotes; context-dependent structural characters `[]{}:,` in arrays and objects. `test5` is none of that.

I assume you want the values of `feature.category` to be JSON strings, i.e. `"test5"` (mind the double quotes).

To make them so, use `TO_JSONB` instead of casting to `JSONB`.

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#ftn.id-1.5.8.22.5.9.2.2.1.1.3.4):

> For any scalar other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value, the text representation will be used, with escaping as necessary to make it a valid JSON string value.

```
=> CREATE TYPE my_category AS enum (
 'type1', 'type2', 'type3'
);
CREATE TYPE

=> SELECT TO_JSONB('type1'::MY_CATEGORY);
 to_jsonb
----------
 "type1"
(1 row)
```